# Angular2 - heavy computation + loader show / hide - my DOM doesn't match what's on the page

Tags: angular, dom, angular2-changedetection

I'm working in Angular 2, trying to show a loader before a heavy computation and hiding it afterward. When I show the loader, the DOM is updating, but the view is not repainting. Therefore, my loader never appears.

Full code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/heavy-computation-problem).

How is this possible?

Comment: We cannot help without the full code... look at this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhsqff

Comment: Can you make the question a bit more clearer. 
The way you have written detectChanges() in ngOnInit() this gets executed only during the component load. If that is the case, i don't see the point to use detectChanges(). Is there any action/function through which you want to trigger change detection ?

Comment: @Sébastien see my changes to the question, I've attached the full code.

Comment: @RaviSankarRao The idea is to detect changes in the "show" variable every time the loader state changes. I referenced the full code in the edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Issue

The issue was that my browser was freezing from the heavy computation. The browser didn't have a chance to repaint after I showed the loader, because when it tried to repaint, the heavy computation was blocking the stack.

---

### What we want on the stack

1. Loader reveal
2. Browser repaint
3. Heavy computation
4. Loader hide
5. Browser repaint

In other words, we want to ensure the loader reveal goes on the stack BEFORE the heavy computation (I will call this function "H") goes on the stack, so that "H" doesn't block the stack while the browser tries to repaint.

---

### How we get this on the stack

I figured out the solution by watching a [brilliant video](https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ) about asynchronicity / event loops / task queues / etc.

The solution is:

```
<loader-show>
setTimeout(() => {
   <heavy-computation>
   <loader-hide>
}, 20)
```

wrap both "H" and the loader hide inside a `setTimeout`. This way, the loader reveal will go on the stack, then "H" and loader hiding will go to the task queue, and will only be pushed onto the stack (executed) when the stack is empty (ie. *after* loader reveal).

BUT notice the "20" ms delay in `setTimeout`? Another critical element from the video is that

> the browser repaints every 16 milliseconds

meaning that my `setTimeout` has to delay by >16 seconds in order to *ensure* that the browser will repaint the view before "H" executes and blocks the stack.

---

### Other Tips

- Move your heavy computation to the backend.
- Use a CSS-based loader.

---

### Reference Code

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/heavy-computation-solution) is the solved code.